# After migrating from MYSQL, mysqli_query() function is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I found four articles about the same issue and I tried their answers with no luck.

My issue is when I tried to migrate from (**MYSQL**) into (**MYSQLi**) and I did it carefully and by the book, but I had the error (**Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli**) pointing to the following line:

```
$IDS = mysqli_query($Connection, $SQL1);
```

**opendb.php**

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
$Connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){

    die("Database connection failed: " 
    . mysqli_connect_error()
    . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
}
?>
```

**The code I'm having issue with:**

```
require_once("../includes/opendb.php");
$SQL1 = "SELECT EmployeeID, Name FROM employees;";
$IDS = mysqli_query($Connection, $SQL1);
if (!$IDS) { 
    die("Error " . mysqli_error($Connection));
        }
require_once("../includes/closedb.php");
```

**closedb.php**

```
<?php
if (!empty($Connection)) {
mysqli_close($Connection);
}
?>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Please let me know if you need more details . Thank you.

Comment: In your php.ini file check if you have activated the extension of mysqli
on **Windows**: 
`extension=php_mysqli.dll`
on **Unix**
`extesion=php_mysqli.so`

Comment: Try without actually closing the connection. Maybe you're closing it somewhere else.

Comment: After you connect, you need to select a database prior to queries.. `mysqli_select_db($Connection, "DB-with-employees-table");`

Comment: @DuaneLortie A DB is being selected in the constructor, `$Connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);`

Comment: I just checked the ini file, the extension is there. As for closing the connection, I tried without it based on other answers and I had the same issue.

Comment: yes noticed that just after commenting  :/

Comment: Let's try to make `var_dump($Connection)` just before your mysqli_query. What would it print?

Comment: Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer. I did a search on all PHP files and found the function:

```
mysqli_close($Connection);
```

At the end of the (functions.php) which was included through:

```
include("functions.php");
```

So basically the function closed the connection before I start the query which generated the error.
Thanks to everyone who took the time trying to solve this.